# How can i improve training loss since it was not decreasing

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I've tried to train this model but after 10 epochs,  training loss does not seem to decrease. what i have done was changing learning rate, batch size and increasing the complexity of the model and it did not work. I was training this model with 500 samples and expecting the model to start overfiting. Did i do something wrong?

I'm using crossentropy loss and adam optimizer with learning rate of 0.0001
Here's my code

```
class FeatureExtraction(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_shape, output_shape):
        super().__init__()
        self.Conv_block1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=input_shape,
                      out_channels=64,
                      kernel_size=3,
                      padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=64,
                      out_channels=64,
                      kernel_size=3,
                      padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=64,
                      out_channels=64,
                      kernel_size=3,
                      padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2)
        )
        self.Conv_block2 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=64,
                      out_channels=128,
                      kernel_size=3,
                      padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=128,
                      out_channels=128,
                      kernel_size=3,
                      padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=128,
                      out_channels=128,
                      kernel_size=3,
                      padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2)
        )
        self.Conv_block3 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=128,
                      out_channels=256,
                      kernel_size=3,
                      padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=256,
                      out_channels=256,
                      kernel_size=3,
                      padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=256,
                      out_channels=256,
                      kernel_size=3,
                      padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2)
        )
        self.Conv_block4 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=256,
                      out_channels=512,
                      kernel_size=3,
                      padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=512,
                      out_channels=512,
                      kernel_size=3,
                      padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=512,
                      out_channels=512,
                      kernel_size=3,
                      padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2)
        )

        self.classifier = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Flatten(),
            nn.Linear(in_features=512*7*7,
                      out_features=512),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(in_features=512,
                      out_features=64),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(in_features=64,
                      out_features=2)
        )

    def forward(self, X):
        X = self.Conv_block1(X)
        X = self.Conv_block2(X)
        X = self.Conv_block3(X)
        X = self.Conv_block4(X)
        X = self.classifier(X)
        return X
```